# How to create CSR in Azure?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-web-app-service

I have bought my domain from whois and my site (Asp.Net MVC) in deployed in Azure. I want to add SSL which I want to buy from GoDaddy.com. To do that I have to generate CSR (certificate signing request) in Azure so that I can use it to get my SSL certificate from GoDaddy.

So how can I generate CSR in Azure?

Comment: @timiTao: please do not add code formatting to names of programming languages. The names themselves are not code. Initial caps (or all-caps for acryonyms) are fine.

Comment: Amit, please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can't generate CSR in Azure. We could used IIS ,Certreq.exe or [makecert.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386968(v=vs.85).aspx) to generate your certificate request, install the certificate to your local machine, and then export the certificate to PFX. More details about **how to bind custom-ssl**, please refer to [official tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-ssl). The following is details about how to use makecert.exe to create CSR:

Create a cert with [makecert.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386968(v=vs.85).aspx) that is under the VS folder after install the VS. The following code is just for demo

```
 makecert -sky exchange -r -n "CN=[CertificateName]" -pe -a sha1 -len 2048 -ss My "[CertificateName].cer
```

[image]

After that we could export Base64-encoded .cer file

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Update:**

Requirements for your SSL certificate, the following is the snippet from the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-ssl#prerequisites)

> To use a certificate in App Service, the certificate must meet all the following requirements:
>
> **Signed by a trusted certificate authority**
>
> Exported as a password-protected **PFX** file
>
> Contains private key at least 2048 bits long
>
> Contains all intermediate certificates in the certificate chain

If we want to use self signature certificate we need to [Export a Certificate with the Private Key](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754329(v=ws.11).aspx). And then we could follow [official tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-ssl) to upload the .**PFX** file to Azure WebApp.

**Note:**  If we use self signature certificate , it will be not trusted.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helps. Just one thing.. in this above solution, I don't have to buy any SSL certificate from any vendor and that the certificate has been created by makecert.exe free of costs ? Can I just upload this certificate to Azure and add binding for my azure website ?

Comment: If we use self signature certificate , it will be not trusted. I will update the answer.

Comment: @Tom this is incorrect. **.cer** files cannot be uploaded to the Azure App Service certificate blade.

Comment: @KaushalKumarPanday. OP mentioned that want to generate CSR  for buying SSL certificate, not upload  certificate  to azure webapp. As I mentioned [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-ssl) in the answer, we need to upload PFX file to azure app service.

Comment: @Tom You may need to edit your answer then as it is very confusing. **Amit** has mentioned that he wants to use the certificate to provide SSL support, whic means he needs a .PFX file and not .cer. You have provided detailed instructions with screenshot for exporting the certificate in .cer format, which doesn't server any purpose and it wasn't asked at all.

Comment: @KaushalKumarPanday Thank you for your suggestion, I will update the answer.

Comment: I agree with @KaushalKumarPanday. I not only want to buy a new certificate (and generate new CSR) from Godaddy but also to upload &  to be supported by my Azure website..

Comment: I have updated the answer about how to upload the certificate to the azure webapp. We could get the detail steps from the [official tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-ssl).

Answer (score 1):

Azure doesn't provide any mechanism to generate CSR. There are several ways to generate CSR:

- Using certificate MMC
- Using IIS Manager
- using certreq.exe
- using openssl
- and many more

I would suggest you to use the Digicert's CSR generation tool. It can be used to generate a CSR and then you can use this to submit to GoDaddy. Here are the instructions on how to do this: [CSR Creation in Azure App Service](https://www.digicert.com/csr-creation-ssl-installation-windows-azure-website.htm)

Once you submit the CSR to the CA, they will provide you a .cer/.crt/.der file, which doesn't contain the private key.

You will first need to import this certificate to bind the private key with the cert. Once done, export the certificate with the private key so that you can generate a **.PFX** file, which the Azure App Services needs. You can again use **Digicert's certificate utility** to export the certifiate in pfx format. See this: [How to Export Your SSL Certificate w/Private Key Using the DigiCert Certificate Utility](https://www.digicert.com/util/pfx-certificate-management-utility-import-export-instructions.htm)

Or you can use the certificate console via MMC. See this:

- [Add the Certificates Snap-in to an MMC](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754431(v=ws.11).aspx)
- [Export a Certificate with the Private Key](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754329(v=ws.11).aspx)